# How to animate the filling of a background color on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am working on a custom Angular component that currently looks like the following:

[image: Slider]

The small green portion that you see on the left is my attempt to have a separate `div` overlap so that when I click on one of the white circular selectors, the green is filled up until that point.

Here is the code I have:

```js
var shell = document.querySelector('.shell');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner-shell');

shell.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  alert("in");
  if (ev.path && ev.path[0].className === 'indicator') {
    var targetNode = ev.srcElement;
    var centerX = targetNode.offsetLeft + targetNode.offsetWidth;
    var centerY = targetNode.offsetTop + targetNode.offsetHeight;

    inner.style.width = `${centerX + 40}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
.inner-shell {
  background-color: #6FBC92;
  width: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.shell {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 3px 28px;
  width: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-shell">
    <div class="shell">
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is what I am getting with the code above (I clicked on the last indicator to get to this state):

[image: Slider2]

How can I instead place `inner-shell` on top of the `shell` but still underneath the `indicators` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `inner-shell` inside `shell` and use `position:absolute` to make overlap on the indicators

See code snippet:

```js
var shell = document.querySelector('.shell');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner-shell');

shell.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.path && ev.path[0].className === 'indicator') {
    var targetNode = ev.srcElement;
    var centerX = targetNode.offsetLeft + targetNode.offsetWidth;
    var centerY = targetNode.offsetTop + targetNode.offsetHeight;

    inner.style.width = `${centerX + 40}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
.shell .inner-shell {
  background-color: #6FBC92;
  width: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.shell {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 3px 28px;
  width: 13px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:111;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="inner-shell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I keep the `inner-shell` underneath the `indicators` ? I need to be able to click on any of the `indicators` at any time so that I can re-position the slider.

Comment: @User5842 use z-index to bring forward the indicators, see my update

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linear-gradient`, here is a simplified example that you can adjust:

```js
var shell = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');

for(var i=0;i<shell.length;i++) {
  shell[i].addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      var centerX = ev.target.offsetLeft - ev.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + 15;
      ev.target.parentNode.style.backgroundSize =centerX+'px 100%';
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin:5px auto;
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
  border-radius:30px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(green,green);
  background-position:left;
  background-size:0px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:grey;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  transition:1s all;
}
.container > div {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```